# '!' history expansion character in bash gives 'not found'

Tags: bash

I use a bash shell from command prompt window on my Windows 7 machine. I can do 'history' and get the list of commands in history buffer but when I do '!12' to reexecute command number 12, I get '!12 not found'.

I searched for a solution and found that by default the expansion character is set to '!' but could not find a way to check if it is set to something else.

-MG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the history command expansion character using the [`histchars`](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_60.html#IDX163) shell variable. The default is `!^#` -- the first character is the history expansion character, the second is the quick expansion character (e.g. for `^X^Y^`), and the third is the comment character.

You also need to check that `!`-style history expansion is on. Use `set -H` to turn it on and `set +H` to turn it off.

Comment: $ histchars='!'
$ echo $histchars
!
$ history
1       histchars='!'
2       echo $histchars
3       history
$ !2
!2: not found -- I tried to reset but does not seems to work.

Comment: On my machine, setting it to less than 3 characters causes problems. Try `histchars='!^#'`.

Comment: $ !^# 2
      !^#: not found

Comment: -H is an unknow option for me.

Comment: What `bash` are you using?

Comment: It's unlikely, but maybe your shell doesn't even have that shell expansion ability...I'm afraid this is probably the limit of my helpfulness :-\

Comment: Thanks nneonneo. I will continue to read the documentation to see if I can learn anything.

Comment: I found a solution. Type ghist and select the command from the list to rerun.